# Copy files from external Hard Drive to local disk

Tags: python, file, copy, hard-drive

I am trying to write a program to copy user profile data from an attached HD to the local HD.  This would copy from a person's old computer to new computer, so all the directories already exist.  I am using the dir_util.copy_tree because it will copy the folder data to an already existing destination path.  In this case the local disk is C and the attached disk is F.  When I do a print of the file paths everything looks good.

```
import distutils.core
input_source = input('Enter User Name: ')
source_drive = input('Enter source drive letter: ')
directories = ["\\My Documents", "\\Favorites", "\\Desktop"]
for directory in directories:
    source = source_drive + ':\\Users\\' + input_source + directory
    destination = 'C:\\Users\\' + input_source +  directory
    distutils.dir_util.copy_tree(source, destination)
```

I am getting the following error when trying to run it.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Eric\Documents\KoelCopy\KoelCopy.py", line 9, in <module>
    distutils.dir_util.copy_tree(source, destination)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\distutils\dir_util.py", line 124, in copy_tree
    "cannot copy tree '%s': not a directory" % src)
distutils.errors.DistutilsFileError: cannot copy tree 'F:\Users\Nick\My Documents': not a directory
```

I assume this is happening because python cannot find the external drive.  I have searched quite a bit, but I cannot find any examples of code like this to know what I am doing wrong.  Do I need to tell the program how to get to this source drive?  Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Are you sure `My Documents` is actually a directory and not just a shortcut to another directory?

Comment: Wow, I am an idiot.  You were right, it links to just Documents.  Some times it just takes another set of eyes, thank you very much.